# Discrete? Functions

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

I have a very basic question.
Suppose that we have a function $f$ defined over a binary choice-
one that I can label by $0$ or $1.$ As such, the domain of the function
is simply $\{ 0 \} \cup \{ 1 \}.$ What is the conventional way to define this mapping
to the real number line?  Thanks.

Comment: Note that the domain of $f$ is $\{ 0, 1 \}$. By definition, for each $x \in \{ 0, 1 \}$, the map $f$ should assign exactly one real number to $x$; so we have not many choices of $f$.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you asking for. I don't think these kind of function have a commonly used name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notation...
$$
f : \{0,1\} \to \mathbb R
$$
This function $f$ has as domain the two-element set $\{0,1\}$, and has values in the set $\mathbb R$ of real numbers.

To "define" such a function, I could write something like:
$$
f(0) = 12,\qquad f(1) = 32
$$

Comment: Note that this is basically $\mathbb{R}^2$. We can just as well represent it by an ordered pair of reals.